# Error callback doesnt have the details in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, backbone.js

I am calling an ajax call in my app and my error callback doesn't have the error details in internet explorer, all other browsers working fine

```
app.api.remoteUpload(dataCall, url, function (data, status) {
    alert(data);

},
function (error, status) {
    alert(error);
});
```

alert(error) is an empty object in ie for error condition, all the others browsers it is working fine. Any thoughts ?

Thanks,

Comment: What version(s) of IE?? Also what are you expecting the alert to contain? if you `alert()` an object, you'll always get `Object object`, regardless of what its contents are. Maybe you should use the `console.dir()` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: ie8 is the version, console.log(JSON.stringify(error)) is empty in ie